Necessary and Sufficient Conditions to Obtain Power Law from Distribution over Exponential Functions?
What properties on distribution $p(x)$ are (1) sufficient and (2) necessary to make
$$-\log \Bigg(1 - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} p(x) \, (1-x)^k \, dx \Bigg)$$
result in a power law
$$\propto k^{-b}$$
for some constant $b > 0$?
I have an implicit assumption that the distribution $p(x)$ "nice" in some sense, but I'm not sure exactly what this assumption is. Perhaps smooth, continuous, something similar?
I've already derived that the Beta distribution and Kumaraswamy distribution are sufficient. Numerically, the continuous Bernoulli distribution works as well. I'm looking for what the general "structure" underlying these distributions is.

Here's a non-rigorous answer.
Sufficient condition. If to leading order $p(x)$ has an expansion of the form $p(x) = A x^{\mu} + o(x^{\mu})$, then your quantity of interest would indeed be a power law $\sim k^{-\mu-1}$.
First, note that it suffices to show that the integral is a power law for large $k$, because $-\log(1- B k^{-b}) \approx B k^{-b}$.
For large k, $(1-x)^k$ is exponentially small in $k$ unless $x$ is very close to 0, so the integral is dominated by small values of $x$. Say $p(x)$ has an expansion of the form described above. Then you can approximate:
$$\begin{align}
\int \limits_0^1 p(x)(1-x)^k dx 
&\approx \int \limits_0^\epsilon A x^{\mu}e^{k\log(1-x)}dx + \text{h.o.t} \\[6pt]
&\approx \int \limits_0^\epsilon A x^{\mu}e^{-kx}dx + \text{h.o.t} \\[10pt]
&= A \Gamma(\mu+1)k^{-\mu-1}+ \text{h.o.t},
\end{align}$$
where $\epsilon>0$ is some small number, $\Gamma$ is the Euler gamma function, and $\text{h.o.t}$ stands for higher order terms. The last equality uses the exponential integral function $E_n(x) = \int_1^\infty e^{-xt}/t^n dt$, and its $\Gamma$ function limit as $x\to 0$. This should give you not just the power law, but also the prefactor.
Necessary condition. Morally speaking, the sufficient condition above should also be a necessary one. But one can imagine all sorts of crazy growth rates, like $e^{-(\log x)^2}$ or the half exponential function -- while I believe these should lead to a faster-than-power-law decay (they seem to me to lie in the limit of $\mu \to \infty$ of the calculation above), I do not know of a general proof of this fact. Here I will show that if $p(x)$ approaches zero like a stretched exponential then the decay is also a stretched exponential in $k$ and thus faster than a power law.
So, assume that $p(x) = Ae^{-c x^{-\nu}} + o(Ae^{-c x^{-\nu}})$, for $x \to 0$. Then
$$\int \limits_0^\epsilon Ae^{-cx^{-\nu}-kx}dx 
= Ak^{-1/(\nu+1)}\int \limits_0^{\epsilon k^{1/(\nu+1)}} e^{-k^{\nu/(\nu+1)}(cz^{-\nu}+z)}dz
\sim e^{-Ck^{\nu/(\nu+1)}}, $$
where the first equality changes the integration variable to $z = k^{1/(\nu+1)}x$, and the last $\sim$ uses Laplace's method for large $k$. Here $C = \max(cz^{-\nu}+z)$, and $\sim$ means asymptotic equality to leading order in the exponent, i.e., $k^{-\nu/(\nu+1)}\log(\text{integral})\to -C$. From Laplace's method you can also get the prefactor to the exponent if you wish.
If $p(x)$ vanishes faster than a stretched exponential then I expect an exponential decay (as the limit $\nu \to \infty$ of the expression above suggests). Indeed, when $p(x)$ is identically zero for all $0\leq x \leq x_0$ where $0<x_0<1$ is some number, then a similar calculation to the one in the sufficient condition yields an exponential decay.

Can I push for a stronger necessary condition(s)?

By stronger, I should have said: Can I please push for a more rigorous proof?

I've just realized that I had a silly sign mistake in the necessary condition calculation (in the the top limit of integration after the change of variables). The corrected calculation resolves the problems I was worried about of the Laplace method maximum falling outside the integration range, and of the approximation of the log in the exponent. The calculation now is on the same level of rigor as the sufficient condition. In light of these corrections, I have changed the entire necessary condition part of my answer.
